# Handling unconventional source directory for a web project in maven

Tags: java, maven-2

I've inherited a web project (Servlets) which is currently build inside eclipse.

I want to add maven around it. But the project's source directory is not following the maven convention. Instead of being inside src/main/java, it's src/package/name/...

I don't want to change anything right now because they are working at full speed towards a milestone. Can I configure maven to accept src/ as the java source directory ? Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add this to your pom in the `build` section.

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
```

Here's the relevant section of the POM doc on [configuring the directories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Element).