# M2E Removes My Source Directory?

Tags: maven, m2e

I have an existing library that I am building in Eclipse and have added the Maven nature to my project using m2e to add dependencies.  When I convert it to a Maven project, my existing source directory (and my bin) become normal folders.  Is there a reason for this?  I am new to Maven, so I am likely doing something wrong, just not sure what...

My project structure is as follows:

```
workspace
  project
    src (in build path)
    resources (in build path)
    bin (output dir)
```

I tried both "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and right click on project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project, and both removed my src and resources folders from my build path, and after changing the structure to the below, changed the output to target/test-cases.  Even if I manually adjust the build path and output, my dependencies don't resolve.

```
workspace
  project
    src (no longer in build path)
    resources (no longer in build path)
    bin  (no longer output)
    target (new output dir)
      test-cases (empty)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the following structure when working with Eclipse (without Maven):

```
/workspace
  /project1
    .project
    /src
    /bin
```

But Maven want to use the following structure

```
/workspace
  /project1
     .project
     pom.xml
     /src
        /main
           /java
           /resources
        /test
           /java
     /target
        /classes
        /test-classes
```

and so on. So it is normal, that the folder `src` is no more directly a source folder for Eclipse, but now there are `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, ...

So it would be easier in the beginning to start with a new Maven project, and move your original sources to the directories they should belong to. Maven has a long tradition with its "convention over configuration", to deviate from that is possible. Have a look at the answer to ["Handling unconventional source directory ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224373/handling-unconventional-source-directory-for-a-web-project-in-maven) to fix this.

Comment: Problem is, this is already in source control so creating a whole new project will be pretty cumbersome.  Is there any way to set things up in place?

Comment: Can't you move folder/files into new folder etc. and transfer the old structure to a new one ?

Comment: So I tried both "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and Configure -> Convert to Maven... and both leave my project without source folders.  Even if I manually add them, my Maven references do not resolve (i.e. log4j).  Any ideas?