# How to compile a Maven project with different sources directory

Tags: maven

I just created a sample Java program.

My source tree looks like below

```
[sathish@oc3855733574 java_tools]$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
├── src1
│   └── FirstProg.java
```

I have created a simple pom.xml file as shown below

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>src1</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-prog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src1</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build> 
</project>
```

When I try to do `mvn package`, maven throws the error message as follows.

I understand it looks out for `src/main/resources` but can't I compile using 'my own' directory structure?

```
INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ first-prog ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ first-prog ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling unconventional source directory for a web project in maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224373/handling-unconventional-source-directory-for-a-web-project-in-maven)

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the default folder structure? Do you have good reasons to do ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I just started learning maven.  But, the primary reason is our company has decided to move away from 'ant' to 'maven' where we have different folder structure

Comment: @Mifeet Can I have multiple <sourceDirectory> tags?  Please let me know whether that's possible

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.

The whole point of Maven is convention over configuration and in this case the convention is to use the generators and then customise.