# Best Practices on refering to resource files in Java code by relative path?

Tags: java, maven, assets

I have a repository which looks something like this:

```
/
/resources/resource1.txt
/resources/resource2.txt
/code/
/code/C/...
/code/java/pom.xml
/code/java/src/main/XYZ.java
/code/java/src/main/ABC.java
```

In other words, there is a maven project rooted in `/code/java/`, and there are resource files located at `/resources/`.

Now, I want to refer to the resource files in my code. The code will be something like the files in `/code/java/src/main/XYZ.java`. How should I refer to this file?

I do not want to hard code the filepath from my local machine. For example, I do not want something like `/Users/agnishom/projectX/resources/resource1.txt`. This will make it difficult for other people who clone my repository to make it work.

I would like to be able to name a file by their relative path, possibly relative to the `pom.xml` file.

What is the best way to do this? Moving the resource files into the `/code/java/` is not an option because they are shared by other projects which are not part of the java

Comment: You say “ there is a maven project rooted in /code/java/”, but then the Java source should be under `/code/java/src/main/java`.   Still, you can use the `..` parent directory notation to keep the paths relative (eg try `../../resources` )

Comment: @racraman yes you are right about the file paths. I have corrected them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling unconventional source directory for a web project in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224373/handling-unconventional-source-directory-for-a-web-project-in-maven)

Comment: First follow convention over configuration paradigm and structure your project different. Source code `src/main/java/<package>` unit- and integration tests into `src/test/java/<package>` and resources which should be packaged with the productive code into `src/main/resources`. Resources which are only needed for unit- and integration testing `src/test/resources` (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: If you follow the conventions it's easy to access resources within Java code via `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource1.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

In the `build` section of your `pom.xml`, you can specify the `resources` directory relative to the project's base directory (/`pom.xml`), as you were suggesting:

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <directory>${basedir}/../../resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

`targetPath` is the path to where included resources should be placed, *relative to the jarfile*/resulting build.

`directory` is the directory to include resources from.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! How do I access the files in this directory with Java?

Comment: You'd use the classloader to include the file like normal resources: `someClassLoader.getResource("myfile.txt")`. You can access the main classloader from any class loaded within your project (e.g. `MyMain.class.getClassLoader()` or `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`.

Comment: Accessing resources via relative path outside the given module is a bad idea.

Comment: @khmarbaise in this case, it sounds like the entire project is multi-language, and it doesn't make much sense to have a `pom.xml` at the top-level if java is a minor part of the project. I assumed that someone cloning the project would be getting everything from OP's top-level (including `/code` and `/resources`).

Comment: Which does not follow conventions which will produce confusion..

Comment: That's why you document these things. Not everything in the world follows convention, and short of "refactor the entire project around Java" I'm not seeing a much easier alternative.